# Android: Best Way to scaling bitmaps for different display sizes?

Tags: android, bitmap, tablet

I am creating a little android game and have a general question:

What is the best way to scale images for different screen sizes (smartphones, tablets etc)? Is it a good idea, just to call `createScaledBitmap(...)` for every bitmap object in the `setSurfaceSize(...)` method of the surface view? So I only need to put the image files in the normal drawable directory?

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to the android way of handling sizes:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

However you are talking about surfaceview, that might have some other tricks.

Put some code so we can see how you are using your surfaceview. Are you using OpenGL f.e.

Comment: In that case it's hard to give any advice